# My app using libsvn-client can't update because of "woking directory xxx is locked." error

Tags: svn

I am developing some kind of version management application using svn library.
For test, I made small application that get the list of the repository.
It works fine. I could get the list of files.
Next, I try to make a app checkout or update.
It use libsvn_client_checkout/update.
Unfortunately, i met "working directory xxx is locked" error message.
I tried several solutions that I found.

1. I chedked that .svn folder have lock file. but, there are no lock file.
2. I turn off the anti-virus and index service of windows. but, it didn't works, too.
3. I tried svn cleanup commend. It is not helpful to my problem.

I use MS Visual Studio 2008 and svn-win32-1.6.13 library on Windows 7 pro.
I also got the same error message from testing on Windows XP SP3.

What's the problem of "working directory xx locked."???????

Answer (score 0):

Since you indicated you are using Windows, have tried shutting down and restarting the computer yet?  Windows is notorious for locking stuff and never letting go until after a restart.  All it takes is one DLL, maybe even the one you're using in your program, to lock onto a file and then no other application can get a hold of it.